# Is there a way to get a list of apps that can be deleted from Android?

Tags: android

Is there a way to get a list of apps that can be removed?

I imported the app list as below

If you import the list as above, you can import the list that cannot be deleted.

I just want to get a list of apps that can be removed, but I don't know how.

Thank you

```
pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
appInfo = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
```

Comment: You can filter the System apps .. See [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply
I've already seen the link, but the app that can be removed doesn't appear in the list(ex.Gboard)