# How can i get all installed applications list in my android app using kotlin language?

Tags: android, kotlin

i am writing an android application that showing all installed applications and apps permissions. I am writing this app. using kotlin. Is there any way to get all installed applications from package manager I AM NOT USING JAVA.

Comment: You can easily convert java code into kotlin in android studio

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
val packages = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)

for (packageInfo in packages) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Package name:" + packageInfo.packageName)
}
```

You can also check this article to check how it works in Android 11:

https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-get-users-installed-apps-in-android-11-b4a4d2754286

Answer (score 0):

```
  val mainIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
    val pkgAppsList = context.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the below snippet you can get details of the installed app on a device

```
val packages: List<ApplicationInfo> =
    pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)

for (packageInfo in packages) {
    Log.d(
       "log",
        "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName
    )
    Log.d("log", "Source dir : " + packageInfo.sourceDir)
    Log.d(
       "log",
        "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)
    )
}
```

This is already answered the question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097838/10516463) in java. I just convert that into kotlin in IDE

Code->Convert java file to Kotlin

It works fine