# PackageManager not returning correct packages with targetSdkVersion 30

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-package-managers, target-sdk

I am using the `PackageManager` to get a list of all packages installed on the user's device. This is working perfectly fine, until I switch from targetSdkVersion 29 to 30.

When I increase the targetSdkVersion from 29 to 30, the `PackageManager` is not returning the correct list of packages anymore (I'm making a launcher and in fact, it is barely returning any packages that can be launched).

I tried `pm.getInstalledPackages(0)`, `pm.getInstalledApplications(0)` and the method for retrieving apps as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run). None of them worked, and all of them were working previously.

The build.gradle version settings:

```
compileSdkVersion 30
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 29
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ephemient pointed out in his comment of his answer, using  [`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES) solved it.

This is done because of the restricted access apps have from Android 11 onwards, as [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9) explains well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a declaration to your manifest in order to see other packages when targeting Android 11 (API 30): https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility

In particular, if you're building a launcher,

```xml
<manifest>
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent>
  </queries>
  ...
</manifest>
```

would allow all results that

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

could match to be returned.

Comment: There is also [`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES) if you need results from `pm.getInstalled*()`. But the intent query should be what a launcher actually needs.

Comment: I actually had these declarations set in the manifest already, but your comment of using the permission was the solution for me. With that permission, it is working well again! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JornRigter , Wanted to ask whether you were testing on an android 11 device as well? Might be facing a similar issue as my app is on target sdk version 30 but the issue is occurring on an android 10 device.

Comment: @a.utfull.day I was working on a device with Android 10, but this applied to all Android versions, since the permission seemed to be needed when going from targetSdkVersion 29 to 30.