# Android Service queryIntentService returns empty list

Tags: java, android, android-studio, service, android-service

I'm trying to get app list using services. I'm using **queryIntentActivities** to get app list. I believe the problem is giving the wrong permissions from manifest but i couldn't figure it out. Does anyone have an idea on this ?

Thanks for any help!

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> allApps = packageManager.queryIntentServices(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : allApps) {
        Log.d("Labels", (String) resolveInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));
    }


    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

and there is how i call this service from activity

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyService.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    startService(intent);
```

here is the manifest file.

```
     <service android:name=".MyService"
         android:permission="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

         </intent-filter>

     </service>
```

Comment: I believe the problem is giving the wrong permissions in manifest but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696617/10980926) help you?

Comment: nope bro i'm trying to get application infos from service not activity