# Android Studio: PackageManager package not found | How to access packages on Android 11?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I am trying to run this sample code from [TutorialPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-launch-another-app-from-your-app) but it is always showing toast

```
Intent launch = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
    if (launch != null) {
        startActivity(launch);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(P01.this,
                "There is an issue running this code!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Can someone please help with how to rectify it!

After requesting help over here, I searched for something relevant on Stack Overflow and came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run).
I used it to display all packages on my device, but instead, it only listed a handful:

```
ResolveInfo{f1539ce com.android.settings/.Settings m=0x108000}
ResolveInfo{6fa90ef com.android.vending/.AssetBrowserActivity m=0x108000}
ResolveInfo{8b2b7fc com.android.stk/.mtk.StkLauncherActivityII m=0x108000}
ResolveInfo{10f4e85 com.dsaghicha.uscs407practicals/.MainActivity m=0x108000}
```

The last one being my app's package.
If I run the above code on any one of these packages it will run

Apparently, I am using Android 11 and there is a privacy policy that restricts package visibility on Android 11.
[Read more](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility)
Now, how to access the package on Android 11?

Comment: Please someone help

Comment: Is your device have Youtube app?.

Comment: @JackHuynh Yes I m running it on my physical device.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/"));
            intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
            PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> info = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
            if (info.size() > 0) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                //No Application can handle your intent
            }

Comment: Could you try it.

Comment: @JackHuynh it didn't work. It straight went to the else block.
I also got a warning:
`Consider adding a <queries> declaration to your manifest when calling this method `

Answer (score 6):

In Android 11, a new Privacy Policy Update restricts package visibility to your android app.

So, you have to explicitly request access to the package by declaring it in the **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.google.android.youtube"/>
</queries>
```

Adding this piece of code to AndroidManifest.xml resolved the issue in my case.

Resources:

- [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility)
- [Medium Article by Yacine Rezgui](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9)

Comment: Appreciate you brother. Been looking for this all day