# Finding installed application domains in Mobile

Tags: android

I have two questions:

1. Is applicationId which is set in defaultConfig in build.gradle(:app) the application domain ?
2. Is there a way to see installed application domains in an android mobile device?
   Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app domain is indeed what you set at the application id

> Sun recomends that you use your company's Internet domain name (which
> is known to be unique) written in reverse. You then use subpackages
> for different projects. For example, horstmann.com is a domain that
> one of the authors registered. Written in reverse order, it turns into
> the package com.horstmann. That package can then be further subdivided
> into subpakcages such as com.horstmann.corejava.

From the Revised and Updated Java SE 6. Core Java.

See [How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run) for how to get a list of installed applications and their domains

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
//get a list of installed apps.
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
    Log.d(TAG, "Source dir : " + packageInfo.sourceDir);
    Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
}
```